# Unable to figure out a deadlock situation

Tags: multithreading, deadlock, semaphore

I was exploring semaphore in *The Little Book of Semaphores* and came across the below example. (aArrived and bArrived refers to two semaphores)

> **Thread A**
>
> 1.statement a1
>
> 2.bArrived.wait()
>
> 3.aArrived.signal()
>
> 4.statement a2
>
> **Thread B**
>
> 1.statement b1
>
> 2.aArrived.wait()
>
> 3.bArrived.signal()
>
> 4.statement b2

Both threads execute concurrently and the constraint is to guarantee that a1 happens before b2 and b1 happens before a2.

Now in the book it was mentioned that this is a deadlock situation.

My request to the audience is that to explain why the deadlock occurs in this solution, as I am unable to figure it out.

Also there were two more solutions given which did not lead to any deadlock . If in the above solution there is a deadlock, then how come there is no deadlock in the below solutions:

Solution2:

> **Thread A**
>
> 1.statement a1
>
> 2.aArrived.signal()
>
> 3.bArrived.wait()
>
> 4.statement a2
>
> **Thread B**
>
> 1.statement b1
>
> 2.bArrived.signal()
>
> 3.aArrived.wait()
>
> 4.statement b2

Solution3:

> **Thread A**
>
> 1.statement a1
>
> 2.bArrived.wait()
>
> 3.aArrived.signal()
>
> 4.statement a2
>
> **Thread B**
>
> 1.statement b1
>
> 2.bArrived.signal()
>
> 3.aArrived.wait()
>
> 4.statement b2

Answer (score 0):

In your first solution, both threads are blocked in step `2`, waiting for the respective other thread to signal them to continue.

The behavior here is that for every thread, the condition to signal the other thread to continue is that *they themselves have been signaled already*. This of course won't work out: Everyone is just waiting and no one ever gets signaled.

The other two solutions work around this problem by having at least one of the two threads send the signal to the other *before* waiting for their own signal to arrive.